# Why would a motor have 100kW in 90kW out?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, induction-motor, electric-machine

I might have phrased my question wrong but our lecturer asked us a question about why a motor (or generator I am not sure) would have 100kW in and 90kW out. He proceeded with saying that it had something to do with saving potential energy. He mentioned that when the motor isn't being used the excess energy is used to pump water higher up in a dam so the water can be used later on to generate energy. I am not sure about what exactly he told us, I probably don't know the process right because I didn't hear him clearly. I would appreciate the exact reason why a motor or generator would have 100kW in 90kW out, thanks in advance. Also, could I get good book suggestions to learn more about DC machines, asynchronous motors/generators, etc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinorwig_Power_Station

Comment: THose are just typical efficiency values with 10% loss

Comment: Imagine 2 GW surge to make tea just before Coronation Street starts

Comment: Bearings have friction losses, winding losses etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is simply about "pumped storage" hydroelectric. It's referring to limits and losses in the process. They might not be electrical.

Remember during the pandemic when the cost of a barrel of oil *went negative* because no one had anywhere to put the surplus? It can cost more to shut down and restart a power plant than to keep it up - so the same thing can happen on the electric spot market.  Equipped hydro dams buy that dirt cheap midnight power, and pump water *back up the dam* from a large reservoir at the bottom.  (if they have such a reservoir. Most of the dams in the Los Angeles Water System were specifically built for this, because the water system knew it would be buying biblical amounts of electricity from the market.  So this lets them use the facilities they already need, to arbitrage cheap midnight power for valuable 5pm power.)

Now you'd think "Oh, they have special pumps for that" - no.  By and large they can run the generators/turbines *in reverse*, making the generator into a motor and the turbine into a pump.  This is efficient enough that it's not worth maintaining separate motors-pumps.  But they can't be *perfectly* optimized for both, especially if this is a retrofit.

The "100 kW / 90 kW" disparity refers to that.

Perhaps they *could* run the generator/motor at the full 100 kW when back-pumping.  But due to being optimized for generating more than back-pumping, doing so over-stresses the system.  As example, back-pumping requires suction out of the turbine outlet pipe. What if running at full power caused *cavitation* (pulling total vacuum so bubbles start forming?) Cavitation is extremely destructive, so they'd have to back the power off.

Answer (score 1):

From your information it is hard to say. So this is just a guess.
It seems it was two different but somehow connected issues.

1. Efficiency of a motor / generator

1 Motor or generator is never 100% efficient. 90% Efficiency seems a reasonable ballpark figure for a modern electric motor. Depending on construction and mode of operation it van be higher or lower. So If we put 100kW of electric power into a motor we only get 90kW of mechanical power out (and 10kW mostly in the form of heat).

Same for a generator: If we put 100kW of mechanical power on the shaft we're getting 90kW of electrical power out if the generator is 90% efficient.

2. Energy storage
   What he was probably describing was [pumped hydro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumped-storage_hydroelectricity). If energy prices are low (normally when demand is low and production high, for example at night) they use pumps to pump water up in the storage basin. And when prices are high (normally during high demand times like cold winter days or really hot summer days) they let the water they have pumped up run the turbines which power the generators that than give that power to the grid.

Now you'll have losses in this system because nothing is 100% efficient. Let's say we use 100kW for one hour to pump water up into the basin. So we use 100kWh of energy. Our motor is 90% efficient, so we can drive the pump with 90kW. The pump is 90% efficient, so we're pumping Water uphill that has 81kWh of potential energy (ignoring all other possible losses). Now when we need that energy and let it run downhill on our turbine. Pelton turbines are amazing and have an efficiency of 95% to 97%! And our generator is a good one and also has 93% efficiency. This gives a total of 90% Efficiency...

So we have a chain of efficiencies and can just multiply them (we're converting the percentages to decimal for this)
Motor, Pump, Turbine, Generator
0.9 * 0.9 * 0.97 * 0.93 = 0.73 => 73% of total efficiency. So by using 100kWh we only get 73kWh back.

So you might (rightfully) ask:"Why do we waste so much energy? And how can companies make money off of wasting energy?"

That's because the electrical grid can't store energy. Production and consumption **must always** be balanced. If there is too much energy, the frequency and voltage in the grid raises which is not good. And if there is more demand than supply than the voltage and frequency fall until the grid collapses. And like other markets, prices rise when the demand is high and are low when there is low demand.

Pump storage buys when it's cheap, sells when prices are high and in the process helps stabilize the grid. I'd call that a win-win situation.

Comment: So the 100 in 90 out part still depends on the efficiency. I am pretty sure he did not mention anything about efficiency but the pump thing you mention sounds like what he told us. Thank you for answering.

Comment: He did!  100 in and 90 out!  So 10kW losses.  You are confusing what the pump is doing with the operation of the pump.